# How to handle If external api failed to call

Tags: c#, blazor, webapi

Actually I want to show the custom message in my blazor application if internet disconnect when cal the webapi. If internet disconnect at the time web api failed to cal and webapi status null.
I had used already try and catch block. In try block api called at the time catch block can not caught the exception.once api failed when internet disconnected at the time error will shown on browser like"failed to loa the resource:ERROR_INTERNET_DISCONNECT"

How to handle this switchvation for show the custom message.

please helpme. Thanks

once api failed when internet disconnected at the time error will shown on browser like"failed to loa the resource:ERROR_INTERNET_DISCONNECT"

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
try
{
    //API call
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // Handle disconnected internet
    if (ex.Message.Contains("The remote name could not be resolved"))
    {
        // Show message
        _errorMessage = "Your internet connection is disconnected. Please 
check your internet connection and try again.";
    }
    else
    {
        _errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Already I had tried this but not working....

Comment: please give another way to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ErrorBoundary tag to wrap a component or page which does the api call, and show a friendly message this way.

```
    <ErrorBoundary Context="ex">
        <ChildContent>
            @Body
        </ChildContent>
        <ErrorContent>
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="card-title mb-3 text-danger">Oops!</h5>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p>Sorry there was an error fetching data</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ErrorContent>
    </ErrorBoundary>
```

If you want to wrap a component change @Body to

also you have ex.Message etc available if you want to present that in your custom error.

Thanks,

Rob