# I want to catch the exception if external api failed when internet disconnected

Tags: c#-4.0, blazor, hosted-blazor-webassembly

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Result>> searchresult(string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        rootdata = await HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsync<Rootdata>(httpClient,$"https://expressentry...");
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
    }

    addresslist = rootdata.d.Results.ToList();

    return addresslist;
}
```

In this scenario, an unhandled error occurred in the browser and check on inspect shows

> Failed to load resource:ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECT

but I want to handle that exception.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You have not indicated how you want to handle the error.  To handle the error, you include your code in the `catch(...)` section.

Comment: Btw, this line `addresslist = rootdata.d.Results.ToList();` will fail if there is an exception (since `rootdata` is only initialized with a successful response from the HttpClient)

Comment: external api failed in try block but catch block didn't caught the exception when internet disconnected

Comment: You are catching the wrong exception type

Comment: This question was asked 3 days ago by a person with a very similar name - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75124439/how-to-handle-if-external-api-failed-to-call

Answer (score 1):

because you are trying to catch the error with `WebException` and `ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECT` is `HttpRequestException` change `WebException` to `Exception` to get all exceptions

something like this:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Result>> searchresult(string searchText)
{
    var addresslist = new Rootdata();
    try
    {
        rootdata = await HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsync<Rootdata>(httpClient,$"https://expressentry...");

        addresslist = rootdata.d.Results.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return addresslist;
}
```

Comment: Already I had tried this but not workig for handle the exception when internet disconnected

Comment: Are you sure? I've tested in Edge

Comment: sorry.it's working but so many HttpRequestException situations. Now when internet disconnectd at this time we got httprequestexception but we get status null. how can identify httprequestexception occured due to internet disconnected.please help me.thanks

Comment: The inner exception is "System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSException" seems also a generic exception, the message is "TypeError: Failed to fetch" you can use it to be more precise.

Comment: I want to show the custom message if internet disconnected only but failed to fetch happened may be another switchvation not for internet disconnect. If any possibility there to get "ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECT" keyword in catch block because this thing show on network tab

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using the wrong exception, I feel your pain trying to get an appropriate error message from API faults.

I use `PostAsync` and `GetAsync` instead so I can get an actual `HttpResponseMessage` back from the request. Now I can check for `StatusCodes` as well as get access to the content returned by the server.

If the server returned content I find that's usually the best API specific error message. The http `StatusCodes` will be generic and not specific to the API. An exception itself could be anything. So when I get the error I prioritize;

- Response Content

  - Example: *"The API key is invalid. Max lengh 255."*
- Response StatusCodes

  - Example: *"401 : Unauthorized."*
- Exception messages

  - Example: *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*

That might look something like this:

```
string error = string.Empty;
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
try
{
    response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("some request");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Do work
    }
    else
        error = await HandleError(response);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    error = await HandleError(response, ex);
}


private async Task<string> HandleError(HttpResponseMessage response, Exception ex = null)
{
    string error = string.Empty;
    // If the API returned a body, get the message from the body.
    // If you know the content type you could cast to xml/json and grab the error property opposed to all of the content.
    if (response != null && response.Content != null)
        error = $"{response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase} {await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}";
    else if (response != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        error = $"{response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}"; // Fallback to response status (401 : Unauthorized).
    else if (ex != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        error = ex.Message; // Fall back to exception message.
    else
        return "Unhandled";

    return error;
}
```